# MySQL query find matching column based on another column?

Tags: mysql

Sorry I don't know how to word the question's title.
I have a table like this

```
Prod       Part      Number

0001       101       3
0001       102       2
0001       103       1

0002       101       3
0002       102       2
0002       103       4

0003       101       2
0003       102       3
0003       103       6

0004       101       3
0004       102       2
0004       103       1
```

I want to find the product that has the correct number per part for all parts.
So something like

```
SELECT Prod from table 
WHERE     (Number of Part(101)) = 3 
      AND (Number of Part(102)) = 2 
      AND (Number of Part(103)) = 1
```

Output would be:

```
Prod
0001
0004
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please provide the desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: @PM77-1 updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some inner  join

```
  select t1.Prod from 
  ( select Prod 
  from my_table 
  where part = 101
  and Number = 3 )  t1
  inner join  
  ( select Prod 
  from my_table 
  where part = 102
  and Number = 2 )  t2 on t1.Prod = t2.Prod
  inner  join 
  ( select Prod 
  from my_table 
  where part = 103
  and Number = 1 ) t3 on t1.Prod = t3.Prod
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/014fe4/8

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I only get one column? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/014fe4/4

Comment: @J13t0u  answer update .. hope is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but it is extremely slow when it gets to 10+. I'm just going to use another table.

Comment: How many  rows  in the table ?  .. and have you  a composite index on (part, number, prod) ?

Answer (score 0):

Through conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Prod, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Part = 101 AND Number = 3 OR
                     Part = 102 AND Number = 2 OR
                     Part = 103 AND Number = 1 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sum
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Prod
HAVING sum = 3
```

This will give you an extra column.  If it's a problem then wrap everything into another SELECT.

Comment: Tried to do that on sqlfiddle, can't seem to get it working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/014fe4/5

Comment: Cannot access Fiddle at the moment.  Will try when I'm back home.